# Split data frame into groups by time and apply a function to multiple columns using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data frames sg is as following:

```
           time                B   C D
1  2014-08-04 00:00:04.0       red 0 0
2  2014-08-04 00:00:06.0       red 0 0
3  2014-08-04 00:00:06.0       red 1 0
4  2014-08-04 00:00:06.2       red 0 0
5  2014-08-04 00:00:06.5       red 0 0
6  2014-08-04 00:00:07.0       red 0 1
7  2014-08-04 00:00:07.7       red 0 0
8  2014-08-04 00:00:16.0       red 0 0
9  2014-08-04 00:00:17.0       red 1 0
10 2014-08-04 00:00:18.0       red 0 0
11 2014-08-04 00:00:22.0       red 0 0
12 2014-08-04 00:00:22.0       red 0 0
13 2014-08-04 00:00:22.2       red 0 0
14 2014-08-04 00:00:25.0       red 1 0
15 2014-08-04 00:00:27.0       red 1 0
16 2014-08-04 00:00:28.0       red 0 0
17 2014-08-04 00:00:29.0 red/amber 1 0
18 2014-08-04 00:00:29.0 red/amber 1 1
19 2014-08-04 00:00:30.0     green 0 0
20 2014-08-04 00:00:40.0     green 0 1
21 2014-08-04 00:00:42.4     green 0 0
22 2014-08-04 00:00:43.0     green 0 0
23 2014-08-04 00:00:50.0       red 1 0
24 2014-08-04 00:00:51.2       red 0 0
25 2014-08-04 00:00:52.0       red 0 1
26 2014-08-04 00:00:52.0       red 1 0
27 2014-08-04 00:00:52.2       red 1 0
28 2014-08-04 00:00:52.9       red 1 1
29 2014-08-04 00:00:53.0       red 0 0
30 2014-08-04 00:00:59.0       red 0 1
31 2014-08-04 00:01:02.0       red 0 1
32 2014-08-04 00:01:03.2       red 0 1
33 2014-08-04 00:01:04.0       red 1 1
34 2014-08-04 00:01:06.4       red 0 1
35 2014-08-04 00:01:07.5       red 1 1
36 2014-08-04 00:01:08.0       red 0 1
37 2014-08-04 00:01:08.2       red 0 1
38 2014-08-04 00:01:08.4       red 0 1
39 2014-08-04 00:01:11.0       red 0 1
40 2014-08-04 00:01:13.0       red 0 1
41 2014-08-04 00:01:14.0       red 0 1
42 2014-08-04 00:01:15.0 red/amber 0 1
43 2014-08-04 00:01:15.0 red/amber 0 1
44 2014-08-04 00:01:16.0     green 0 1
45 2014-08-04 00:01:21.0     green 0 0
46 2014-08-04 00:01:26.0     green 0 0
47 2014-08-04 00:01:31.0     amber 0 0
48 2014-08-04 00:01:31.0     amber 0 0
49 2014-08-04 00:01:34.0       red 0 0
50 2014-08-04 00:01:36.0       red 0 0
```

First, I need to split the data frame into groups by time interval(for example 10 seconds). 
Second, calculate the percentage of value "1" in each group for columns C and D separately.
Finally, plot the percentage for column C and B with time in a graphic.

I did it for single variable. 
My solution is :

```
percentage.occupied <- function(x) (NROW(subset(x,C==1)))/(NROW(x))

splitbytime <- ddply(selectstatus309, .(cut(time,"10 seconds")),percentage.occupied)
colnames(splitbytime)<-c("time","occupancy")

occupancy  <- ggplot(splitbytime, aes(x=(as.POSIXct(splitbytime$time)),y=occupancy)) +
                      geom_point(shape=1) +
                      geom_smooth()+
                      xlab("time") +
                      ylab("% occupancy")
```

**The graphic is looks like the following pic, I plot it for column C. What I need is to plot the percentage for C and D respectively in one graphic.**

I am not sure if I describe my question clear  (┬＿┬)

### [image]

I took BrodieG's solution and apply it to a period time(1 hour) of my data. I followed each step but plot something wrong: 
[image]
Besides, there is an error:

```
geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is <1000, so using loess. Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
Error in smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, data, knots) : 
  x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k.
```

I guess the error is not the reason for the strange plot.
You can see there is one part of the melted df as following, from which I refer the result is impossible to be just 1 or 0.

```
 time          B variable value
10520 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10521 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10522 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10523 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10524 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10525 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10526 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10527 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     0
10528 2014-08-04 15:10:00      green     dt_5     1
10529 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     1
10530 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     1
10531 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     1
10532 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     1
10533 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     1
10534 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     1
10535 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     0
10536 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     0
10537 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     0
10538 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     0
10539 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     0
10540 2014-08-04 15:10:00      amber     dt_5     0
10541 2014-08-04 15:10:00        red     dt_5     0
10542 2014-08-04 15:10:00        red     dt_5     0
10543 2014-08-04 15:10:00        red     dt_5     0
10544 2014-08-04 15:10:00        red     dt_5     0
10545 2014-08-04 15:10:00        red     dt_5     0
```

The code is here:

```
selectstatus309.mlt <- melt(selectstatus309,id.var=c("time","B"))

percentage<-
  ggplot(selectstatus309.mlt, aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))+
  stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y =mean,shape=1)+
  stat_smooth()+
  facet_wrap(~ B)
```

Sorry for the looooong and verbose story! T。T

Comment: `percentage.occupied <- function(x) (NROW(subset(x,C==1)))/(NROW(x))` == `mean(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option.  First we make our cut time data:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df$time <- as.POSIXct(cut(as.POSIXct(df$time), "10 secs"))
```

Then we melt it so the values in `C` and `D` are in the same column so we can use that as an aesthetic.  **This is the key step to have the two plots in the same graphic as you want**.  Inspect `df.mlt` to see how it is different from `df`.  `ggplot` likes data in long format to use it's built-in data segmentation tools.

```
df.mlt <- melt(df, id.var=c("time", "B"))
```

Then we use `stat_summary` to plot the dots (no need to resort to `ddply`):

```
ggplot(df.mlt, aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y=mean, shape=1) + 
  stat_smooth()
```

produces (on your subset of data):

[image]

Note how I'm able to split out the data by whether it is "C" or "D".  You can even facet by B:

```
ggplot(df.mlt, aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y=mean, shape=1) + 
  stat_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~ B)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems a much better solution. But when I tried 'df$time <- as.POSIXct(cut(as.POSIXct(df$time), "10 secs"))' to cut the df, the values of time lose time part and only have date part left. It was not be cut.

Comment: It works by 'cut(as.POSIXct(df$time),"10 secs")'. Your answer is brilliant, I would like to vote up twice :p

Comment: @Chenlu, glad this help.  Note that the date is not cut, it's just the way GGPlot is chosing to show it.  You can modify it with: `+ scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%b-%d %H:%M:%S"))` or some such, though if you do that you probably want to also `+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))`.

Comment: Hi, @BrodieG, what's the meaning of 'fun.y = mean'? My plot only have one value "1" or "0" in each group. The result must be wrong, but I couldn't think out which step is wrong.

Comment: @Chenlu `stat_summary` will group all the like `x` values together (in your case, all the observations in each 10 second bucket), and then apply a function to the corresponding `y` values.  `fun.y=mean` means that you want to apply `mean` to your `y` values.  For each point, the summarized `y` value will be computed as `mean(c(0,1,0,0,0,1))` (numbers made up).  This can return only zeroes and ones if each group has only one data point (this is the case with the "amber" group above), or if a has all values of either zero or one alone.  Subset your data.frame to the trouble group to check.

Comment: Thank for the clear explanation! Your solution is great, the reason I got only two separate values is that "0""1" were treated as factor. I understand it.